# Updated RealmObject when read via Backlink is null

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm

I'm updating an object & then accessing it via `Backlink`. It has not worked yet.

```cs
class Person : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Dog> Dogs { get; }
}

class Dog : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Ignored]
    public Person Person
    {
        get                 
        {
            if (_person == null)
                _person = Persons.First();

            return _person;
        }
    }  

    [Backlink(nameof(Person.Dogs))]
    public IQueryable<Person> Persons { get; }
}
```

Add:

```cs
var dog = new Dog () {Id = 1};
var person1 = new Person () {Id = 1, Name = "Person1"};
person1.Dogs.Add(dog);
realm.Write(() => realm.Add(person1));
```

Update:

```cs
var person11 = new Person() {Id = 1, Name = "Person11"};
realm.Write(() => realm.Add(person11, true));
```

Read:

```cs
var readPerson11 = realm.All<Dog>.First().Person;
```

I get an exception on the `Person` property.

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element occurred.

(If `readPerson11` is read without updating it, then I get back the `person11` properly.)

I've tried `realm.Refresh()` after updating & before reading Person.
Also tried `GetBacklinks<Person>(nameof(Person.Dogs))` with no result.

Help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the update overrides all values of the `Person` object. If you check, after the update, `person11.Dogs` will be empty. So when updating, you need to supply the entire collection of dogs assigned to this person. One way to do it would be to use the old values:

```
var currentPerson11 = realm.Find<Person>(1);
var person11 = new Person() {Id = 1, Name = "Person11"};
foreach (var dog in currentPerson11.Dogs)
{
    person11.Dogs.Add(dog);
}
realm.Write(() => realm.Add(person11, true));
```

Alternatively, you can invert the relationship - rather than have a list of Dogs assigned to a person and backlinks on the dog object, you can have a `Person` property on the `Dog` class and backlinks on `Person`:

```
public class Person : RealmObject
{
    // ... other props

    [Backlink(nameof(Dog.Person))]
    public IQueryable<Dog> Dogs { get; }
}

public class Dog : RealmObject
{
    // ... other props

    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Then updating the person will not affect their Dogs collection.